# Abort commit/add if file does not match rule in gitattributes

Tags: git, gitattributes

Basically the title says it all.

If for some reason a file in my current repository does not match any pattern in the gitattributes file it should abort adding/commiting the file.

I want to use this to make sure we don't rely at all on core.eol, core.autocrlf and core.safecrlf.

The [manpage on gitattributes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) does not say anything at all about this. Nor any other topic on gitattributes i have found so far.

Comment: The basic rule of attributes is: every file always has attributes, and the files in the man page let you override git's default computations.  You *might* (I don't know, haven't tried this) be able to get what you want by having a final default attribute matching `*`, that sets a "clean" filter that is "required", like the "crypt" example in http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes (just make the filter always fail, so that the add is aborted).